# why doesn't this rewrite the url properly?

Tags: mod-rewrite

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?new.php?url
RewriteRule ^/?(.+)\.?(.+)$ new.php?url=$0 [L]
```

its supposed to take any URL

```
mysite.com/someurl
```

and convert it to

```
new.php?url=someurl
```

however it keeps going to just new.php

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1616719/need-a-regex-to-match-url-without-http-https-ftp, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1616770/help-rewriting-this-url-simple-but-not-working

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the second question mark in the first line so it matches a literal question mark:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?new.php\?url
```

Also you are not using the parenthesized groups on the second line. `$0` is okay, or you may want `$1` instead. If you use `$0` you could simplify it a bunch:

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ new.php?url=$0 [L]
```

Or on the other hand if you're breaking apart the URL for a reason I would suggest some fixup. You're not matching the file name and extension exactly right. A little more complex regex like this would probably do you better:

```
RewriteRule ^/?(.*?)(?:\.([^.]*))?$ new.php?path=$1&extension=$2 [L]
```

Explanation:

1. `(.*?)` matches the directory and file name. The `?` means match non-greedily, so stop as soon as the next part matches. The parentheses cause it to be captured and stored in `$1`.
2. `(?:\.([^.]*))?` matches the file extension. `?:` turns says to not capture the outer set of parentheses, so the dot is not captured in `$2`. `([^.]*)` matches the extension and ensures that it does not contain a dot. The final `?` makes the file extension part optional, just cause not all URLs have file extensions. Thus there will only be a `$2` if there is a file extension.

Answer (score 0):

The first back-reference is `$1` not `$0` AFAIK. If that doesn't do it try specifying [QSA] as well, though I doubt that's it.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?new.php?url
RewriteRule ^/?(.+)\.?(.+)$ new.php?url=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

**The first back reference should be $1 instead of $0.**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?new.php?url
RewriteRule ^/?(.+)\.?(.+)$ new.php?url=$1 [L]
```

It also depends on what other lines of code you have in the file. It's also possible to mess up rewrites if you have another code that conflicts with it.