# Need a regex to match URL (without http, https, ftp)

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite

I am working on a regex to match URLs without `http`, `https` or `ftp` in the beginning. Basically, I need it for mod_rewrite:

Examples:

```
www.someurl.com/blah/blah/balh/etc/and/so/on
crazy.something.net/agjja
something.us/index.php?
```

So, I can do

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} URLregexhere
RewriteRule ^URLregexhere$ ping.php?url=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1616770/help-rewriting-this-url-simple-but-not-working

Answer (score 0):

You want to match everything?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?ping\.php
RewriteRule (.*) ping.php?url=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

By definition everything that the regex in a RewriteRule is receiving is a URL (since it's fed the URLs for requests, and nothing else), so the match-all regex `(.*)` is all you need.