# help rewriting this url. simple but not working

Tags: mod-rewrite

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?ping.php
RewriteRule ^/\?(.*)$ ping.php?url=$1 [L]
```

i am trying to match any character that follows `/?`

```
 www.mysite.com/?someurl.com
```

instead it keeps loading the index.html !

Comment: Shouldn't this be on serverfault?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1616719/need-a-regex-to-match-url-without-http-https-ftp

Answer (score 0):

You cannot match the query string with mod_rewrite, but if you still want to pass it on, you can add %{QUERY_STRING} to the resultant url, for example

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ ping.php?url=%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```